# Mansion point and incenter

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

In acute triangle $ABC$, $AB>AC$. Let $I$ the incenter, $\Omega$ the circumcircle of triangle $ABC$, and $D$ the foot of perpendicular from $A$ to $BC$. $AI$ intersects $\Omega$ at point $M(\neq A)$, and the line which passes $M$ and perpendicular to $AM$ intersects $AD$ at point $E$. Now let $F$ the foot of perpendicular from $I$ to $AD$.
Prove that $ID\cdot AM=IE\cdot AF$

What I thought: Notice that $\triangle IDE$ and $\triangle AFM$ are similar after some angle chasing.

Comment: If $IDE$ and $AFM$ are similar, then $ID/IE=AF/AM$, which is the relation you want to prove.

Comment: What is the meaning of "Mansion" in your title ?

Comment: This is question 2 from the [2019 Korean National Olympiad](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1953582).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

COMMENT:

You correctly found that $\triangle IDE≈\triangle AFM$.We rewrite the required relation as:

$\frac{AF}{AM}=\frac{ID}{IE}$

That is triangles IAE and DIE must be similar. These two triangles have common angle $\angle IED$, therefore we must have:

$\angle IDE=\angle EIA$

This is not possible because:

$\angle IDE=\angle BDE (=90^o)+\angle BDI$

$\angle EIA=\angle EIF (≠90^o)+\angle FIA(=BDI)$

Comment: Great observation! How can I contact you?

Comment: through this site or  this address (sirous_f20@yahoo.com)